# Fill polygon with range of none-adjacent colors?

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have a layer in QGIS showing U.S. counties.
I would like to color-fill the polygons in a layer using a range of 5 colors, so that no colors are adjacent to each other.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I couldn't get this working with QGIS 2.18, so used an old copy of MapInfo with a plugin called RouteWare ToolBox. It works brilliantly, and adds an integer field to the shapefile with numbers that can then be assigned to a table of colors.

Answer (score 7):

QGIS 3.0 has this ability : just check **topological coloring** in the toolbox processes (in "cartography") ... (u can even choose the number of colours to use - a minimum is automatically computed)

Comment: Can I do it in QGIS 2.18 as well?

Comment: never heard it was available in previous version of QGIS ... maybe via a plugin but i have never seen that.

Comment: I wrote a plugin for QGIS 1.x, did it get ported to 2.x? http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~rowlings/Qgis/Plugins/Documentation/topocolour/

Comment: Here's an implementation for QGIS 2.x: https://gitlab.com/Balaitous/mapcoloring/wikis/home

Comment: @Spacedman - thanks - that seemed to work quite well, but it didn't pick up some counties at all. See 'http://www.gnomeplanet.com/images/map_coloring.png'. This image shows the colored counties, with holes in the new layer showing the original layer, colored red, underneath. The 5m shapefile came from 'https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_counties.html'.

Comment: Those links should not have trailing apostrophes